# do I get leaking or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am getting a leak warning when doing `Analyze` from xcode and the warning looks like the picture below

[image]

However, if I am using `Instrument` to check, I am getting no warning at all for 'Leaks'. Picture is shown below
[image]

Question : Do I getting leaking or not.

Common.m

```
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef  endColor) {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    //CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);--------> this will fix leaking

}
```

Comment: Share the code, your class Common

Comment: Almost certainly you are getting a leak. The probability of a bug in analyzer is very low. Leaks in Instruments are not perfect.

Comment: @Sulthan Now that's faulty information if I've ever heard it.  Instruments is so good, NSObject has to hide some of its memory management internals from it

Comment: @George: see my OP please.

Comment: @Sulthan: why it does not show the leaking

Comment: Why is it commented?//CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);--------> this will fix leaking

Comment: @George: i comment it out because I want to make sure that an 'Instrument' is gonna throw leaking out, but it is not

Comment: Is it even being executed?  Code doesn't leak if it doesn't run.

Comment: @CodaFi : thanks for that point. I mistakenly comment out another code that triggers my 'common.m' class

Answer (score 2):

- expand that little triangle and Xcode will show you the execution path that leads to the leak
- yes that code is leaking color spaces
- that Allocations graph sure does look like a leak, but that is pretty steep for color spaces unless you are creating *a lot* of them!
- [heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) will likely be helpful.